# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have the following code where it seems that userManager creates a different DBContext and my companyListService uses different DbContext. As a result I get the error message saying

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker

```
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _companyListService.AddCompanyList(
                    new CompanyList(_userManager.FindById(GetUserId()), vm.Name));

                   _companyListService.SaveCompanyList();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _nlogger.Error(e);

                    ViewData["EditError"] = e.Message;
                }
            }
```

How could I fix this problem? Is there any way stop tracking in userManager dbcontext? Or a better way to use the same dbcontext? The application uses Identity 2.

I can change my code to pass the userId instead of user object which solves the problem but I would like to pass the user object in.

When I turn off the tracking by

```
Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

The issue is also resolved but this would break other parts as tracking us required.

What is the best way to overcome this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to detach the entity first from the original tracker.

Comment: Perhaps it is necessary to detach another created `DbContext` using `ChangeObjectState`. Since the entity is not clearly shown there, it is possible using `EntityState.Detached` or simply `Detach()` method to detach used entity.

Comment: How would I detach from the original tracker in the code above? @Maarten

Answer (score 0):

imho, it seems to be a too optimistic design: you assume that your identity database and your business database will always be the same (other way to say: identity user and business use come from the same table).

With the same assumption I could suggest the following code:

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _companyListService.AddCompanyList(
                new CompanyList(_userManager.FindById(GetUserId()).UserPK, vm.Name));
                //------------------------------------------------^
                //or in the optimistic design :):
                //new CompanyList(GetUserId(), vm.Name));

               _companyListService.SaveCompanyList();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _nlogger.Error(e);

                ViewData["EditError"] = e.Message;
            }
        }
```

with

```
public CompanyList(fkUserType fk, string name) {
    UserId = fk;
    Name = name;
}
```

In this case you have to explicitly declare and configure the foreign key of your navigation property.

```
public class CompanyList {
    public CompanyList(fkUserType fk, string name) {
        UserId = fk;
        Name = name;
    }

    public virtual User {get; set;}
    public fkUserType UserId {get; set;}
}
```

As you may have noticed, the constructor no longer use the entity, only the key.